# Content project for an xna library?

Tags: c#, xna

I currently working on a GUI library using XNA. My issue is getting textures for the gui into the library project. Is there a way to use a content project with a library project, or am I looking at this problem the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, you can do this: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282476.aspx)